# JavaScript- Recursion with setTimeout function in randomly index of array is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner of JavaScript and trying to build a web app that can play audio array list. First, the user has to select number of follow-up questions and how long the duration is between each question from array list element 4 to 8. But the program will loop through element 4 to 8 the first no matter what. If the user select a number follow-up question is 6, meaning that after looping through element 4 to 8, it will randomly choose two elements from array element 4 to 8 and play again because it already has played 4 times(element 4 to 8), so it only needs to play 2 times more. If the user select a number follow-up question is 7, then it will play 3 times, so on so forth.

I have tried doing for loop but it doesn't work. People say don't use setTimeout inside of for loop because it acts differently than other programming language. Thus, I'm doing recursion. But when I run my program. It doesn't play audio anymore when index (i) is equal 9 and the number that user selects is greater than 6. Where did I do wrong?

I appreciate any help, thank you so much.
And sorry if I confuse you because of my English. Please let me know if you are confused.

```
<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
</select>

var intro_playList = [{
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "0_silence"
    }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "key": "1_hello"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "2_how_old"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "3_what_did_you_make"
    }, {
        // story_playlist
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "4_tell_me_a_story"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "5_and_then_what"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "6_why"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "7_tell_me_more"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "8_what_happened_next"
    }, {
        "duration": 1500,
        "key": "9_how_does_it_end"
    }, {
        "duration": 1500,
        "key": "10_what_is_the_story_name"
    }, {
        "duration": 1500,
        "key": "11_thank_you_goodbye"
    }];

$(document).ready(function() {

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);

var i = 0;

$("#play").on("click", playAudio);

        function playAudio() {
            var audioIndex = intro_playList[i];
            var numFollowUpQuest = document.getElementById("numFollowUp").value;

            if(i >= 4 && i <= 8){
                intro_playList[i].duration = document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000;

                audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                audioElement.load();
                setTimeout(function(){ audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

            } 

            if(numFollowUpQuest > 4 && numFollowUpQuest <= 20 && i === 9){

                intro_playList[i].duration = document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000;
                numFollowUpQuest = numFollowUpQuest - 4;
                console.log(numFollowUpQuest);

                if(numFollowUpQuest === 1){
                    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((8 - 5) + 1) + 5);
                    console.log("randomInt is " + randomInt);

                    audioIndex = intro_playList[randomInt]
                    console.log(audioIndex);

                    audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                    audioElement.load();
                    setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

                }

                if(numFollowUpQuest > 1){

                    var playNumFollowUp = function(theRestNumFollowUp){
                        var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((8 - 5) + 1) + 5);
                        console.log("randomInt is " + randomInt);

                        audioIndex = intro_playList[randomInt]
                        console.log(audioIndex);

                        audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                        audioElement.load();

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            audioElement.play.bind();

                            if(theRestNumFollowUp > 0){
                                theRestNumFollowUp--;
                                playNumFollowUp(theRestNumFollowUp);

                            }
                        }, audioIndex.duration);                       
                    };
                    playNumFollowUp(numFollowUpQuest);

                }
            }
            console.log("After " + audioIndex.duration + " seconds play next audio");

            audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
            audioElement.load();
            setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);
            i+=1;
    }
```

Comment: what is index(i) here..another user input?

Comment: Thank you for replying. The index(i) is var i = 0; There will be just one user who select numFollowUp and secFollowUp inputs.

Comment: and are you setting the value of i from your code? I mean how does i value becomes 9

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't put every code on here. Please see the updated

Comment: Not sure if I still understand you fully. but for index 9       var audioIndex = intro_playList[i]     becomes array out of bound. My understanding...1) user selects 6, system plays 1-4 serially and and rest 2 audio it plays randomly 2) each audio play is gaped with the values selected in 2nd dropdown.

Comment: I just put more audios in the array. Is this better?  And you are right , sir

Answer (score -2):

Its a prototype should help you to run this sequence in a simple way. I have avoided the actual audio play and mentioned in the console the audio key, start and stoppage after the duration.
this loops runs through first 4 audio files sequentially and then randomizes the rest. Please replace your audio play functionality with the console starts and stops.

```js
var intro_playList = [{
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "0_silence"
        }, {
            "duration": 500,
            "key": "1_hello"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "2_how_old"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "3_what_did_you_make"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "4_tell_me_a_story"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "5_and_then_what"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "6_why"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "7_tell_me_more"
        }, {
            "duration": 1000,
            "key": "8_what_happened_next"
        }, {
            "duration": 1500,
            "key": "9_how_does_it_end"
        }];

        var i = 0;
        var funcs = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#play").on("click", playAudio);
        });

        function playAudio() {
            for (counter = $('#numFollowUp').val() , j=0 ; counter > 0 ; counter--, j++) {
                if (j < 4) { //Normal scenario
                    //Play the audio form the array with a duration specified in the secFollowup
                    funcs[j] = (function (j) {
                        return function () {
                            console.log("Playing Audio no: " + j);
                            setTimeout(function () { console.log("Stopped Audio no: " + j + " after " + intro_playList[j].duration + " ms"); }, intro_playList[j].duration);
                        };
                    }(j));
                    setTimeout(funcs[j], $('#secFollowUp').val() * 1000 * j);
                }
                else {
                    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
                    //Play the audio form the array with a duration specified in the secFollowup
                    funcs[j] = (function (j, randomInt) {
                        return function () {
                            console.log("Playing Audio no: " + j + " randomly.. randomAudioKey = " + randomInt);
                            setTimeout(function () { console.log("Stopped Audio no: " + j + " after " + intro_playList[randomInt].duration + " ms"); }, intro_playList[randomInt].duration);
                        };
                    }(j, randomInt));
                    setTimeout(funcs[j], $('#secFollowUp').val() * 1000 * j);
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp">
    <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp">
    <option value="">Second between each question</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button id='play'>Play</button>
```

Hope it helps..

-Srikant

Comment: Thank you for replying, sir. I will try to understand your prototype and combine it with mine. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Give a thumbs up if it helps you

Comment: Sir, I know it's a prototype but it's not east for me to understand but I'm still trying to understand it. Like I'm not sure when to increment i and play audio files. I did try put audioElement.play() inside of setTimeout function within the if (j < 4). But it gets cut off.  Also, the first 4 audios in the array will play based off the duration in the array. After that, it will be based off user's selection

Comment: Sir, what you suggested doesn't work for playing the real audio files. It will run skip the first element of array and jump to the fourth element of array. And it gets stuck, playing the fourth audio over and over.